# MySQL cpu at 400% on c5.xlarge box

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

Box is running only mysql and CPU is at 400% constantly. I can't seem to find anything that would be causing it. I've changed a few values in my.cnf based on some research, but had no luck reducing the CPU usage.

my.cnf as follows:

```
[mysqld]
basedir=/opt/bitnami/mysql
datadir="/opt/bitnami/mysql/data"
port=3306
socket=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
tmpdir=/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp
#bind-address=127.0.0.1
skip-name-resolve=1
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 64M
table_open_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 40
join_buffer_size = 1M
query_cache_limit=0
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100
max_connections = 100
open_files_limit=30000
# Try number of CPU's x 2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency = 16
```

Comment: You can't "tune your way out of a CPU problem".  Turn on the slowlog with a small value for `long_query_time`.  That will help you find the naughty query/queries.  Present them, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Answer (score 0):

Remove these for a start, they are almost certainly counterproductive:

```
table_open_cache = 256
join_buffer_size = 1M
thread_concurrency = 16
```

There is also a conspicuous absence of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` being set.

Configuration isn't going to be the root cause of your problem, though - you need to identify what queries are eating all of your CPU and address those specifically, either by rewriting them or by making sure that appropriate indexes for them exist.

Comment: @GeorgeMcCann Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: As for the absence of the buffer_pool_size, I have found (so far) that cloud services do a pretty good job of setting that.

Comment: @RickJames the only indication we have here is that it is an EC2 instance, not RDS.